# Issues showing the loaded API data using axios in Laravel 8 using Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel 8 app running with Vue.js. Witch I'm trying to load some data to my project.

I can get the data (also tested when console logging), but when I'm assigning the posts variable, the variable woun't show the data. I see from most example this should work out of the box.

What am I missing here?

```
<template>
        {{posts}}
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            posts: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadPosts();
    },
    methods:{
        loadPosts: function(){
           axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
            .then(response => {
                this.posts = response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: looks correct from the vue end. The issue might be with the data. can you check that it is returning a json array, not some string that just looks like json?

Comment: Yes (type is JSON), im using this: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos (same happens with my own API). Witch is just a return $var

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put {{posts}} inside a root div element:

```
<template>
    <div>{{posts}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the same result (tested with adding that div as well)

Comment: Hi, I tested exactly this code with laravel 8 and I got expected result. Maybe problem is something else. Check console tab and see if there is any error